# Using Attributes for Generic Constraints

Tags: c#, generics, attributes, extension-methods

Given an example such as ..

```
public interface IInterface { }

public static void Insert<T>(this IList<T> list, IList<T> items) where T : IInterface
{
 // ... logic
}
```

This works fine, but I was wondering if it is possible to use an Attribute as a constraint. Such as ...

```
class InsertableAttribute : Attribute

public static void Insert<T>(this IList<T> list, IList<T> items) where T : [Insertable]
{
 // ... logic
}
```

Obviously this syntax doesn't work, or I wouldn't be posting the question. But I'm just curious if it is possible or not, and how to do it.

Comment: I would *LOVE* if this was implemented...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**No.** You can only use (base)classes and interfaces as constraints.

You can however do something like this:

```
public static void Insert<T>(this IList<T> list, IList<T> items)
{
    var attributes = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InsertableAttribute), true);

    if (attributes.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("T does not have attribute InsertableAttribute");

    /// Logic.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I figured, but I thought it was worth a try. My project does not need it, but I figured it was good information to know. I'll click the 'Accept' checkbox in 5 minutes when Stack Overflow lets me.

Comment: If you need the attribute for some external processing, for which an interface that you control is the marker, then you can declare the attribute on the interface and select inherited attributes.

Comment: @Ciel you can anyway have `where S : Attribute` and then do an internal runtime validation..

Answer (score 8):

No. You can only use classes, interfaces, `class`, `struct`, `new()`, and other type parameters as constraints.

If InsertableAttribute specifies `[System.AttributeUsage(Inherited=true)]`, then you could create a dummy class like:

```
[InsertableAttribute]
public class HasInsertableAttribute {}
```

and then constrain your method like:

```
public static void Insert<T>(this IList<T> list, IList<T> items) where T : HasInsertableAttribute
{
}
```

Then `T` would always have the attribute even if it was only coming from the base class. Implementing classes would be able to "override" that attribute by specifying it on themselves.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Ah, of course. I knew I was forgetting something, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score -2):

No you can't. Your question is not about attributes, but object-oriented design. Please read the following to learn more about [`generic type constraint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx).

I rather suggest you do the following:

```
public interface IInsertable {
    void Insert();
}

public class Customer : IInsertable {
    public void Insert() {
        // TODO: Place your code for insertion here...
    }
}
```

So that the idea is to have a `IInsertable` interface, and implements this interface within a class whenever you want to be insertable. This way, you will automatically restrict the insertion for insertable elements.

This is a more flexible approach, and it shall give you the ease to persist whatever same or different information from an entity to another, as you have to implement the interface yourself within your class.

Comment: Well, I don't need to do it at all. It's more of one of those things where you're coding something, and it hits you as an idea that might be useful for something else. In truth, if I were going to need to ensure constraint to an Attribute, I would simply use a dummy class.

Comment: I get your point, and there are some times where you think of something and wonder whether it is doable. =) Interesting question anyhow. =)