# In .Net, why aren't attributes declared on interfaces returned when calling Type.GetCustomAttributes(true)?

Tags: .net, inheritance, interface, attributes, getcustomattributes

In answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146674/using-attributes-for-generic-constraints/4146699) I tried to use `Type.GetCustomAttributes(true)` on a class which implements an interface which has an Attribute defined on it. I was surprised to discover that `GetCustomAttributes` didn't return the attribute defined on the interface. Why doesn't it? Aren't interfaces part of the inheritance chain?

Sample code:

```
[Attr()]
public interface IInterface { }

public class DoesntOverrideAttr : IInterface { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var attr in typeof(DoesntOverrideAttr).GetCustomAttributes(true))
            Console.WriteLine("DoesntOverrideAttr: " + attr.ToString());
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true)]
public class Attr : Attribute
{
}
```

Outputs: Nothing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe attributes defined on implemented interfaces can be reasonably inherited.  Consider this case:

```
[AttributeUsage(Inherited=true, AllowMultiple=false)]
public class SomethingAttribute : Attribute {
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public SomethingAttribute(string value) {
        Value = value;
    }
}

[Something("hello")]
public interface A { }

[Something("world")]
public interface B { }

public class C : A, B { }
```

Since the attribute specifies that multiples are not allowed, how would you expect this situation to be handled?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I hadn't thought about how allowing this would be like opening the multiple-inheritance can of worms. Good answer!

Comment: Thanks! I like answering questions with more questions. :)

Answer (score 4):

Because the type `DoesntOverrideAttr` doesn't have any custom attributes. The Interface that it implements does (remember, a class doesn't inherit from an interface...it implements it so getting attributes up the inheritance chain still won't include attributes from interfaces):

```
// This code doesn't check to see if the type implements the interface.
// It should.
foreach(var attr in typeof(DoesntOverrideAttr)
                        .GetInterface("IInterface")
                        .GetCustomAttributes(true))
{
    Console.WriteLine("IInterface: " + attr.ToString());
}
```